# Flutter keyboard not showing in ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm running my app in ios simulator but why is my keyboard not showing all of the sudden when I click on the textfield? It works perfectly fine before I fix my app icon.

[image]

Tried deleting the app and re-install it again, but still won't work. When I run the app on android and click on the same textfield, the keyboard is showing.

Here is the code:

```
                       TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          controller: inputTextController,
                          onChanged: (text) {
                              if (!_isWriting){
                                _isWriting = true;

                                  //update typing status when type messages
                                  var msg = {};
                                  msg["api_key"] = apiKey;
                                  msg["type"] = "status_typing";
                                  msg["id_sender"] = idUser;
                                  msg["id_receiver"] = idReceiver;
                                  msg["room_id"] = conversation!.roomId;
                                  String msgString = json.encode(msg);
                                  homes.channel.sink.add(msgString);

                                setState((){});
                                Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).whenComplete((){
                                  _isWriting = false;
                                  setState((){});
                                });
                              }
                            },
                          maxLines: null,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13, bottom: 13),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'Type a message',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff99999B),
                              )
                          ),
                        ),
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you please add code what you have written for textfield.

Comment: Write from keyboard working ?

Comment: @aufa You want to seen keyboard in simulator?

Comment: I've updated my question, please have a look @PratikButani

Comment: Yes, when I write from keyboard it works but the keyboard is not showing in the simulator @RaviLimbani

Comment: @aufa i added answer let its try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For show keyboard in simulator follow this command

```
cmd + shift + k
```

Comment: @aufa If its works for you verified it and give up vote for encourage Thanks.

Comment: ah i see, but it can't write from my laptop keyboard anymore?

Comment: If you want to write from your laptop keyboard you can directly write

Comment: tried writing from my laptop but it didn't work anymore

Comment: @aufa When you open keyboard in simulator  writing from laptop doesn't working

Answer (score 0):

goto I/O menu in Simulator window and inside keyboard unclick "**connect hardware keyboard**" or open simulator window and press **cmd+shift+k**